# Jenkins can't restore .net core project

Tags: .net, jenkins, .net-core, nuget

I set up Jenkins to download a .net core project from a git repository and then execute the command

```
dotnet publish
```

When I run the command outside Jenkins, in the same machine, it works. When I let Jenkins run the command it can't download any packages.

```
The HTTP request to '...' has timed out after 100000ms. Failed to download package '...'
```

The server is a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 r2.

Comment: How are you executing the commands inside jenkins?

Comment: I use "Execute windows batch command" in build steps. @JRichardsz

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2945   I think is a nuget issue.  Your package is public or private?